# Соотношение потоков в Java с потоками в ОС

Tags: java, многопоточность, jvm

Как потоки в Java соотносятся с потоками в операционной системе ? Например, в UNIX системах есть системный вызов thread. Вызывается ли он при создании нового потока ?

Возможно я плохо гуглил, но не нашел ничего в интернете. Было бы клева увидеть ссылку на какую-нибудь статью по теме.

Comment: Насколько я помню, спецификация по этому поводу не обязывает на каждый тред выделять поток в ОС. Поэтому всё зависит от той или иной реализации JVM

Comment: В спецификации не указано, как их имплементировать, но hotspot и производные используют треды ОС. Ситуация может сильно разнообразиться через пару релизов т.к. разработчики сейчас обсуждают добавление новых возможностей и т.н. green threads (контекстов выполнения, существующих только внутри VM).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В HotSpot под Linux и Windows потоки Java выполняются потоками операционной системы. Из [HotSpot Runtime Overview](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/RuntimeOverview.html#Thread%20Management%7Coutline):

> The basic threading model in Hotspot is a 1:1 mapping between Java
>   threads (an instance of java.lang.Thread) and native operating system
>   threads. The native thread is created when the Java thread is started,
>   and is reclaimed once it terminates. The operating system is
>   responsible for scheduling all threads and dispatching to any
>   available CPU.

Answer (score 4):

[Use the Source, Luke](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Use%20the%20Source%2C%20Luke) - да пребудут с тобой исходники!

Если посмотреть на исходники [Thread в OpenJDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.start%28%29), то там при запуске треда явно виден вызов нативного метода:

```
private native void start0(); //вызов нативного метода
```

Что автоматически означает вызов библиотечной Си функции, реализация которой зависит от платформы. Я склонен думать/верить, что для Linux это будут треды ОС.

Comment: Вообще много слухов, что происходит под капотом. Есть версия, что JVM (от oracle) держит пул процессов и в них запускает потоки. Все это для платформонезависимости. Может быть такое ?) Или это противоречит ключевому слову `native` в вашем примере ?

Comment: @faoxis как в составе JDK так и среди утилит операционной системы есть масса средств посмотреть, как ведёт себя запущенная JVM. Под Linix можно, например, посмотреть вывод `ps -eLf | grep jvm`. Только надо учесть, что кроме запущенных вами в программе потоков, JVM со старта запустит ещё пачку background system threads.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а разве ps не для просмотра процессов, а не потоков ? Мне кажется, что довольно проблемно соотнести эти процессы с потоками `jvm`.

Comment: @faoxis ключ `-L` выводит информацию о потоках.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev пробовал использовать ключ `-L` - ничего не показывает (нет результата), хотя в `ps -ef | grep jvm` процесс есть.

Comment: @faoxis треды в Linux тоже имеют `pid`'ы, и в целом очень похожи на процессы и показываются многими утилитами, перечисляющими процессы. Я впервые с таким столкнулся в `htop`. В режиме дерева (включается по `F5`) особенно наглядно, треды располагаются под процессом, которому принадлежат. Не помню, правда, включен ли показ тредов по умолчанию.